# How to properly send binary messages using websocket from node.js without libraries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

The fact is that I'm trying to implement the dependency free websocket server, I found a couple of articles on this topic in English. and Russian, but in both articles only processing of "short" text messages is considered, unfortunately nothing is said about binary ones. And at the moment, apparently, I do not have enough qualifications to understand how to send binary messages (with text messages everything is ok, thanks to the articles I can both receive and send them without any problems). In this connection, I ask for help here. If any of you can provide an example of how binary messages are sent, I would really appreciate it. Please do not post links to existing libraries implementing ws in node.js, I tried looking at their source.

Comment: This is a tough question to get help with here.  You don't show any of your code and you seem to not think that looking at existing implementations is going to help you.  Not sure what else to suggest.  There's a spec and there are existing implementations.  Use those to learn.  That's how anyone does this.  Unless this is an academic or curiosity exercise, it's hard to understand why you don't just use a solid, existing and well tested implementation.  To me that's what nodejs is all about - you can use lots of existing, well tested and supported code to more quickly accomplish your goal.

Comment: I could show you an article from which I am trying to learn how to do this. Yes, this is an academic problem and I tried to look at the existing implementations, but now I can't figure it out. Maybe it would be more correct to say, to comprehend this in order to be able to use these examples, so I am asking the question here.
https://medium.com/hackernoon/implementing-a-websocket-server-with-node-js-d9b78ec5ffa8

Comment: Well this site is generally for problems with code and we can't really help you with your code problem without seeing the relevant portions of your code.  Though, there are probably very, very, very few people here who know anything about the internals of a webSocket server implementation, even fewer who know about the binary aspects.  If it were me and studying the spec didn't answer it for me, I'd be studying other implementations and maybe even comparing network packets between what I'm sending and what some other implementation is sending.

Comment: I guess I hoped that someone here would be able to explain to me if there are differences in the processing of text and binary data in websocket and, perhaps, will show simpler code than what is used in existing implementations. Anyway, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: According to [RFC6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.2) the difference between text and binary data transmission is the value of the 4 bit opcode included in frames used to transmit the data: `1` for text or `2` for binary. So changing the opcode used by a working text websocket server could be a place to start. RFC645 and [its associated updates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6455) are among the input specifications for building a new WS server without using Node libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the specification, I'll try to figure it out again. I thought that opcode 1 or 2 only allows you to determine the type of "arrived" data, but none of the articles I read anywhere explicitly explained why the opcode is still needed

Answer (score 0):

const secondByte = buffer.readUInt8(1);
const isMasked = Boolean((secondByte >>> 7) & 0×1);

One of the articles explaining how to work with this has an example above
Can someone suggest, when the author of the article calculates whether the buffer is masked, it compares with the text opcode, right?